# Rails 4 + bower-rails gem + bower + bootstrap sass

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have installed bower-rails gem

then in bower file I included bootstrap-sass, it installed bootstrap-sass in vendor/assets/bower_components.

Now according to a resource bower-rails automatically takes care of adding bower_components to assets, so I am trying this in application.css

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require 'bootstrap-sass'
 */
```

But it throws me error that bootstrap-sass file not found.

Do I have to manually add vendor/assets/bower_components to assets?

I am pretty new to rails so some explanation would help a lot.

I am following this [resource](http://www.techienov.com/post/install_bootstrap_with_bower/)

EDIT:
On doing `rails c` and printing `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`
I can see `vendor/assets/bower_components` in asset paths
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolved the issue by removing all the bower components and running

`rails g bower_rails:initialize`

It created an intializer for assets bower_rails.rb, which finally solved the problem